# SQL Query from "Triangular Relation" of Tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am having a hard time to get a - seemingly simple - right in SQL. I am using MS Access but I guess it doesn't really matter here.
My data structure looks like this:

[image]

So `tblA` has the "Products", `tblB` the "Components" and `tblC` the "Modules". It's just an example obviously.
`tblA` ("Product") has m:n relation to `tblB` ("Component"), i.e. a product consists of some components and components can belong to many products. `tblB` ("Component") has m:n relation to `tblC` ("Modules"), i.e. a component consists of modules and modules can belong to many components. Now the twist is, that I also have a m:n relation between `tblA` and `tblC`, i.e. a mapping of products and modules. This is due to the fact that the "configuration" of a component can be different depending on the product for which is it. So for "Product 1" "Component 2" needs to consist of "Module 1" and "Module 2" while for "Product 2" "Component 2" is just "Module 2".

I want a query with a result like this

```
|Product|Component|Module|
|-------|---------|------|
|Prod1  |C1       |      |
|Prod1  |C2       |      |
|Prod1  |C2       |M1    |
|Prod1  |C2       |M2    |
|Prod2  |C2       |      |
|Prod2  |C2       |M2    |
|Prod2  |C3       |      |
|Prod2  |C3       |M3    |
```

where I have "Prod1" and "Prod2" in `tblA`; "C1", "C2", "C3" in `tblB` and "M1","M2","M3" in `tblC`. Relations are

[image]

So essentially I want a table with Product, Component, Module that holds all the combinations Product+

Now with a SQL Query

```
SELECT tblA.Product,
       tblB.Component,
       tblC.Module
FROM tblC
INNER JOIN ((tblA
             INNER JOIN (tblB
                         INNER JOIN mapAB ON tblB.[Component] = mapAB.[Component]) ON tblA.[Product] = mapAB.[Product])
            INNER JOIN mapAC ON tblA.Product = mapAC.Product) ON tblC.Module = mapAC.Module;
```

I get

[image]

which is understandable but not what I want. I have tried to do first a join of `tblA` and `tblB` and to combine this with a LEFT JOIN (or RIGHT JOIN) with a join of `tblB` and `tblC` but this gives "unsupported join operation" errors.

Any ideas on how to approach this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your relationships, you haven't used your primary keys to make the one to many relationships, but the data fields.

In this case, this query should work for you:

```
SELECT tblA.Product, mapAC.Module, MapAB.Component
FROM (tblA LEFT JOIN mapAC ON tblA.Product = mapAC.Product) LEFT JOIN MapAB ON tblA.Product = MapAB.Product;
```

All the other tables are in this case just informative since you already have the data available in the tables `MapAB` and `MapAC`.

I would advise using the primary keys in your relationships.

Update:
Your query can follow three routes to get the data you need:

1. tblA -> mapAB + mapAC
2. tblA -> mapAB -> tblB -> mapBC -> tblC
3. tblA -> mapAC -> tblC -> mapBC -> tblB

Depending on which data route you want to follow your query will look differently.

Route 2 Query:

```
SELECT tblA.Product, MapAB.Component, mapBC.Module
FROM (((tblA LEFT JOIN MapAB ON tblA.Product = MapAB.Product) LEFT JOIN tblB ON MapAB.Component = tblB.Component) LEFT JOIN mapBC ON tblB.Component = mapBC.Component) LEFT JOIN tblC ON mapBC.Module = tblC.Module;
```

Route 3 Query:

```
SELECT tblA.Product, mapAC.Module, mapBC.Component
FROM (((tblA LEFT JOIN mapAC ON tblA.Product = mapAC.Product) LEFT JOIN tblC ON mapAC.Module = tblC.Module) LEFT JOIN mapBC ON tblC.Module = mapBC.Module) LEFT JOIN tblB ON mapBC.Component = tblB.Component;
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I think this goes into the right direction. But it not yet gives the result I want. Your query yields all combinations of Components (tblB) and Modules (tblC) and not just the ones that are permitted by mapAC. Probably because mapAC is more or less ignored by the first LEFT JOIN?
On the primary key thing you are right. This was mostly for illustration purpose.

Comment: Please share which data route you want to follow, see the updated answer

Comment: The query I provided, follows route 1

Comment: From the first look at it Route 2 would be my desired path. I kind of tried this by doing (tblaA LEFT (tblAB LEFT tblB)) LEFT (mapBC LEFT tblC). But either I get the syntax wrong or this is not the right way to next the join operations, I haven't got it to work yet.

Comment: looking at your data/structure, and the required result, I don't think you can achieve the result with this structure

Comment: I agree, the data structure probably needs to overhauled for what I want to do. But still, based on your suggestions and after fiddling around a lot, I think I found a (somewhat nasty) way to do it. I will post it separately.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, based on jbud suggestions I was able to build up the desired result like this:

```
qryProdModComp = SELECT tblA.Product, mapBC.Component, mapAC.Module
FROM (tblA LEFT JOIN mapAC ON tblA.Product = mapAC.Product) LEFT JOIN mapBC ON mapAC.Module = mapBC.Module;
```

already almost gives what I want

[image]

Notice however, that the line with Prod1 and C1 is missing (for which no Mx is directly linked).
To get this I added

```
qrySingleC = SELECT tblB.Component AS Component
FROM   tblB
       LEFT JOIN mapBC
       ON tblB.Component = mapBC.Component
WHERE  mapBC.Component Is Null
UNION
SELECT mapBC.Component
FROM   tblB
       RIGHT JOIN mapBC
       ON tblB.Component = mapBC.Component
WHERE  tblB.Component Is Null

qryProdCompOnly = SELECT tblA.Product, mapAB.Component, NULL AS Module
FROM tblA INNER JOIN ( qrySingleC INNER JOIN mapAB ON qrySingleC.Component = mapAB.Component  ) ON tblA.Product = mapAB.Product;

qryOverall = SELECT Product,Component,Module FROM qryProdCompMod UNION SELECT Product,Component,Module FROM qryProdCompOnly;
```

which gives

[image]

Getting to the exact same result as requested in my original post actually looks still a bit cleaner

```
qryProdCompOnly2 = SELECT tblA.Product, mapAB.Component, NULL AS Module
FROM tblA INNER JOIN mapAB ON tblA.Product = mapAB.Product;

qryOverall = SELECT Product,Component,Module FROM qryProdCompMod UNION SELECT Product,Component,Module FROM qryProdCompOnly2;
```

gives

[image]

Comment: would it not be easier to simplify your structure with `tblA, tblB, tblC and mapABC`? This way you have control of the product, component, and module combination. mapABC would contain the fields you require in your result, so no complicated/calculated query would be necessary.

Comment: Yes, I guess it will be easier and I am currently considering to do it this way. This will have impacts in other parts of my data model and I still need to weigh the efforts for this vs. the gained simplicity for this topic...
Anyways, I just wanted to share this approach as it answers my original question. Thanks a lot for your help!